# Updating product quantity invalidates *all* indexes? Can that be right?

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, indexing

I'm scratching my head trying to figure out if this is somehow the appropriate behavior in CE 1.8.1, or if I need to dig deeper in search for a solution.

It seems any change to a product's data, but in this case quantity specifically, results in an invalidation of all my indices except for "Catalog URL Rewrites", forcing me to reindex. And by reindex, I mean a "real" reindex, so with a catalog of 60,000 SKUs it takes several minutes.

So if the indexes are set to "Update on Save" something like cancelling an order results in a timeout error as all the indexes try to run.

Am I missing something here?